# How to create this specific bib template?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apacite

I used to use the `apacite` package for my references, but for this time, I have to use another template and I don't know how to do that.

1. Every citation call-out must appear in footnotes using the following order, for instance:
   Donald Woods Winnicott, Jeu et réalité. L'espace potentiel. Paris : Éditions Gallimard.
2. Every quoted reference must appear in the references section using the same order.

Do you know which package I have to use for this purpose? Do I need to employ `biblatex`?

---

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib,natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{Winnicott1975,
    address = {Paris},
    author = {Winnicott, Donald Woods},
    publisher = {{\'E}ditions Gallimard},
    title = {Jeu et r{\'e}alit{\'e}. {L}'espace potentiel},
    year = {1975}}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Un chapitre}
Some texte\footnote{\citet{Winnicott1975}}.

\bibnewpage 
{%start grouping
    \raggedright 
    %\nocite{}
    \bibliography{mybib}
}%end grouping

\end{document}
```

Comment: References must appear in the footnotes exactly as they appear in the references section, not only as "Winnicott (1975)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like `biblatex`'s `verbose` styles might work for you. You haven't given enough details to say for sure, but the following comes pretty close to what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Winnicott1975,
  address   = {Paris},
  author    = {Winnicott, Donald Woods},
  publisher = {Éditions Gallimard},
  title     = {Jeu et réalité},
  subtitle  = {L'espace potentiel},
  year      = {1975},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some texte\autocite{Winnicott1975}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Donald Woods Winnicott, Jeu et réalité. L’espace potentiel. Paris : Éditions Gallimard, 1975.]

Note that when you use `biblatex` you need to run Biber on your document instead of BibTeX (which you use with `apacite`). [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) may help you setting your editor up to run Biber instead of BibTeX.

If you are generally unfamiliar with `biblatex` [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks! In principle, the citation call-outs must appear just before marks such as dot or parenthesis. It is not the case here.

Comment: @domi That'll be the auto-punct feature. You can turn it off with `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}{\smartcite}{\smartcites}`. (Or more drastically with the option `autopunct=false,`.)

Comment: Terrific! Thanks for your help.