# How to modify this Biblatex style?

Tags: biblatex

In this useful [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651963/how-to-create-this-specific-bib-template), I asked how to use `biblatex`'s `verbose`. Now, I'd like to customize a little this style as follows:

1. Just after the name of the town, there should be a comma instead of a colon.
2. There shouldn't be apostroph for an article title.
3. The name of the journal mustn't be preceeded by the mention "In".

In a nutshell, any trick to customize this verbose style?
This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Winnicott1975,
  address   = {Paris},
  author    = {Winnicott, Donald Woods},
  publisher = {Éditions Gallimard},
  title     = {Jeu et réalité},
  subtitle  = {L'espace potentiel},
  year      = {1975},
}
@Article{Chiantaretto2005,
author = {Chiantaretto, Jean-François}, 
title = {À propos de la première transgression}, 
journal = {Topique}, 
volume = {92}, 
number = {3}, 
pages = {111--125}, 
year = {2005}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \autocite{Winnicott1975} and here too \autocite{Chiantaretto2005}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please ask only about one issue per question. That makes your question easier to answer and much more relevant for future readers. See for example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Comment: For question 1 you could use `style=ext-verbose,` and `\renewcommand*{\locpubdelim}{\addcomma\space}`.

Comment: For question 2 see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864. You'll probably want either `\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}` or just `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\isdot}`.

Comment: For question 3 I'm not quite sure what you mean by review, but assuming you mean the journal(title) of an `@article` entry, you can use `style=ext-verbose,`'s `articlein=false,` option. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864.

Comment: You can modify with the  `xpatch` package.

Comment: A good first start for customising `biblatex` styles is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864.